# Finding rectangles enclosing points

Tags: python, pytorch, parallel-processing, geometry

I have a list of `n` 2D points (x, y) and a list of `m` rectangles (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax). I want to find indices of all rectangles that enclose a point. This has to be done efficiently. GPU is also available. I'm looking at a solution that is heavily parallelised through vectorised operations. For loops are a no-go for me as `0 < n,m < 10^6`

For example:

```
points = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [5, 5]]
rectangles = [[0, 0, 3, 3], [1, 1, 4, 4], [4, 4, 7, 7]]

result:
(1, 1): [(0, 0, 3, 3), (1, 1, 4, 4)]
(2, 2): [(0, 0, 3, 3), (1, 1, 4, 4)]
(5, 5): [(4, 4, 7, 7)]
```

I've written this solution in PyTorch (tried chunking to reduce memory overflow)

```
def find_rectangles_containing_points(points, rectangles, chunk_size=1000):
    n = points.size(0)
    m = rectangles.size(0)

    rectangles_containing_points = []

    for i in range(0, n, chunk_size):
        points_chunk = points[i:i + chunk_size]
        points_expanded = points_chunk.unsqueeze(1)  # chunk_size x 1 x 2
        rectangles_expanded = rectangles.unsqueeze(0)  # 1 x m x 4

        is_inside = (rectangles_expanded[:, :, :2] <= points_expanded) & (points_expanded <= rectangles_expanded[:, :, 2:])

        result = torch.nonzero(is_inside.all(dim=-1))
        rectangles_containing_points.extend([list(rect_ids) for rect_ids in result.t()])

    return rectangles_containing_points

points = torch.rand(1000000, 2)
rectangles = torch.rand(10000, 4)

find_rectangles_containing_points(points, rectangles)
```

However, this solution doesn't scale to larger values of n and m (~10^6). Are there approaches designed for such specific problems?

Comment: `pytorch` defaults to GPU.  You should set the `device` parameter to the gpu you want to use.

Comment: What scaling issues do you have? Does it take too much time? Does it take too much memory? or both?

Comment: Also, are the any bounds on x,y and xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax?

Comment: @YakovDan It takes a lot of time to compute. The scale of n and m ranges in millions.
All coordinate values would be within 500